# Fixing the order of monitors in xorg.conf and configuration dialogs

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, multi-monitor

I have this "3 monitor" setup (it's actually a SINGLE LG 49" monitor which you can configure to look like 3 monitors to the OS, using a DP and 2 HDMI ports) which for the most part works fine... except for a minor problem with some applications incorrectly thinking the leftmost monitor is the primary (even though the middle is marked as the primary for Mint).

I'm thinking that maybe if I can swap that left monitor and the middle monitor, and then just change the "primary" to the one that's currently the left monitor, maybe that problem will be resolved. But whenever I tinker with this stuff things go bonkers. (Usually the resolutions are screwed up and things get "stretched" or "compressed" with no way to change to the correct resolutions.)

As you can see below, these configurations are ridiculously mixed up. None of it makes any sense and almost nothing seems to agree on what the current configuration is! But it does work as one would expect, for the most part.

Can anyone explain what the heck is going on here and how I could possibly clean this up? (I would prefer NOT to mess with the 3 physical wires from the video card to the monitor ports, since there's a KVM involved and some DP/HDMI converters, and they were hell to get working initially.)

[image]
[image]

The monitor's true resolutions match what is shown above in the NVIDIA X Server Settings. I have no idea why the NVidia console things the left monitor is HDMI when the monitor is configured to show DP1 there. The annoying thing is that even if I manage to get the monitors ordered correctly, it doesn't let me choose a correct resolution.

xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 470.57.01


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics LG HDR DQHD"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 135.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 61.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "DP-1: nvidia-auto-select +3840+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +1280+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +1280+0, DP-1: nvidia-auto-select +3840+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

xrandr output:

```
└─$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5120 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1280x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 300mm x 337mm
   1280x1440     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
HDMI-1 connected primary 2560x1440+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 599mm x 337mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+  30.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    23.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected 1280x1440+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 300mm x 337mm
   1280x1440     60.00*+
   3840x2160     29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Trying to figure out what configs I should even focus on, one thing that stands out is xorg.conf where it seems to think the DP-1 output should be offset the most (I guess for the right monitor), but the MONITOR says it's putting DP1 on the left pseudo-monitor... maybe I need to reverse the xorg offsets?

Comment: Your desktop environment might be already overriding parts of the `xorg.conf` configuration using the XRandR extension... run `xrandr` and see what it says about each "display". The `nvidia-settings` panel seems to be taking the `xorg.conf` configuration as gospel truth, and shows the displays as if they'd been arranged according to the offsets specified in there. Yes, you probably should reverse the offsets.

Comment: Added xrandr output

Comment: Yeah messing with the offsets might help but I think I'll probably run into that problem again where the resolutions it tries to display are wrong. The middle only seems to want to show the larger resolution but I think I need the DP1 to do that. Haven't figured out what determines which resolutions are valid for a given output.

Comment: Which GPU do you have? If it's an older one, it might be unable to provide the newer HDMI 2.x or DisplayPort 2.0 signaling modes, which might be required to use the full capacity of your display. Other than that, the "three-screens-in-one" configuration is special enough so it is going to require careful reading of the display documentation, configuring the display to the correct mode for what you want, and then configuring the OS to agree with that.

Comment: NVidia 1080. I think it supports 2.0. But I don't think it's the problem because I'm using 3 outputs, two are HDMI and one DP, and currently the HDMI is handling the largest resolution. It's a single monitor but it should effectively look like 3 different ones.

Comment: Well I managed to find a solution for the particular application that was ignoring Mint's primary monitor selection, but I'll leave this up in case anyone else has any interesting feedback.